# SQL array flattening: Why doesn't CROSS JOIN UNNEST join every nested value with every row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question isn't about solving a particular problem, it's about understanding what's actually happening behind the scenes in a common SQL idiom used to flatten arrays.  There's some magic behind the scenes and I want to peek behind the curtain of syntactic sugar and see what's going on.

Let's consider the following table `t1` :

[image: t1]

Now let's assume we have a function called `FLATTEN` that takes a column of type array and unpacks each of the arrays in that column so that we're left with one row for each value in each array -- if we run `SELECT FLATTEN(numbers_array) AS flattened_numbers FROM t1`, we'd expect the following, which we'll call `t2`

[image: t2]

In SQL, the CROSS JOIN combines rows from two tables by combining each row from the first table with each row from the second table. So if we run `SELECT id, flattened.flattened_numbers from t1 CROSS JOIN flattened`, we get

[image]

Now flatten is just an imaginary function, and as you can see it's not very useful to combine it with a CROSS JOIN, because each of the original values of the `id` column gets mixed with `flattened_numbers` from each of the original rows.  Everything gets mixed up because we don't have a `WHERE` clause that selects only the rows of the `CROSS JOIN` that we want.

The pattern people actually use to flatten arrays looks like this:
`SELECT id, flattened_numbers FROM t1 CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequences.some_numbers) AS flattened_numbers`, which produces

[image]

But I don't understand why the `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` pattern actually works.  Because the `CROSS JOIN` doesn't include a `WHERE` clause, I would expect it behave just like the `FLATTEN` function I outlined above, where every unnested value gets combined with every row from `t1`.

Can someone 'unpack' what's actually going on in the `CROSS JOIN UNNEST` pattern that ensures that each row is only joined with it's own nested values (and not with the nested values from other rows)?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The best way to think about this is by looking at what happens on a row-by-row basis. Setting up some input data, we have:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1] AS numbers_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [2, 4, 5]
)
...
```

(I'm using a third element for the second row to make things more interesting). If we just select from it, we get output that looks like this:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1] AS numbers_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [2, 4, 5]
)
SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+---------------+
| id | numbers_array |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | [0, 1]        |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     |
+----+---------------+
```

Now let's talk about unnesting. The `UNNEST` function takes an array and returns a value table of the array's element type. Whereas most BigQuery tables are SQL tables defined as a collection of columns, a value table has rows of some *value* type. For `numbers_array`, `UNNEST(numbers_array)` returns a value table whose value type is `INT64`, since `numbers_array` is an array with an element type of `INT64`. This value table contains all of the elements in `numbers_array` for the current row from `t1`.

For the row with an `id` of 1, the contents of the value table returned by `UNNEST(numbers_array)` are:

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
| 0   |
| 1   |
+-----+
```

This is the same as what we get with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM UNNEST([0, 1]);
```

`UNNEST([0, 1])` in this case means "create a value table from the `INT64` values `0` and `1`".

Similarly, for the row with an `id` of 2, the contents of the value table returned by `UNNEST(numbers_array)` are:

```
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
| 2   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
+-----+
```

Now let's talk about how `CROSS JOIN` fits into the picture. In most cases, you use `CROSS JOIN` between two uncorrelated tables. In other words, the contents of the table on the right of the `CROSS JOIN` are not defined by the current contents of the table on the left.

In the case of arrays and `UNNEST`, however, the contents of the value table produced by `UNNEST(numbers_array)` change depending on the current row of `t1`. When we join the two tables, we get the cross product of the current row from `t1` with all of the rows from `UNNEST(numbers_array)`. For example:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1] AS numbers_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [2, 4, 5]
)
SELECT id, number
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers_array) AS number;
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 0      |
| 1  | 1      |
| 2  | 2      |
| 2  | 4      |
| 2  | 5      |
+----+--------+
```

`numbers_array` has two elements in the first row and three elements in the second, so we get `2 + 3 = 5` rows in the result of the query.

To answer the question about how this differs from flattening the `numbers_array` and *then* performing a `CROSS JOIN`, let's look at the results of this query:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1] AS numbers_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [2, 4, 5]
), t2 AS (
  SELECT number
  FROM t1
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers_array) AS number
)
SELECT number
FROM t2;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| 0      |
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 4      |
| 5      |
+--------+
```

In this case, `t2` is is a SQL table with a column named `number` with those values. If we perform a `CROSS JOIN` between `t1` and `t2`, we get a true cross product of all rows:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, [0, 1] AS numbers_array UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [2, 4, 5]
), t2 AS (
  SELECT number
  FROM t1
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers_array) AS number
)
SELECT id, numbers_array, number
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2;
+----+---------------+--------+
| id | numbers_array | number |
+----+---------------+--------+
| 1  | [0, 1]        | 0      |
| 1  | [0, 1]        | 1      |
| 1  | [0, 1]        | 2      |
| 1  | [0, 1]        | 4      |
| 1  | [0, 1]        | 5      |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     | 0      |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     | 1      |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     | 2      |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     | 4      |
| 2  | [2, 4, 5]     | 5      |
+----+---------------+--------+
```

So what's the difference between this and the previous query with `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers_array)`? In this case, the contents of `t2` don't change for each row from `t1`. For the first row in `t1`, there are five rows in `t2`. For the second row in `t1`, there are five rows in `t2`. As a result, the `CROSS JOIN` between the two of them returns `5 + 5 = 10` rows in total.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation.  I'd never heard of 'value tables' before and if I google 'SQL value table' I don't find pages that use the term in the sense you do.  Is this an idea specific to BigQuery?

Comment: Also, FWIW: I'm the kind of user who would prefer a little note on this in the official documentation, but I might be in the minority there.  Even though I like the CROSS JOIN UNNEST idiom, I find it confusing when the good old cross join behaves differently than expected for unknown reasons.

Comment: We're working on it :) I've been reviewing changes recently to overhaul how we explain these concepts.

Comment: Irrelevant question but how do you get this neatly formatted results tabled inside "+,-, |" structure?

Comment: Not a near-term thing, but keep an eye on [ZetaSQL](https://github.com/google/zetasql) since I think it will include formatting results in this way once the reference implementation is released.

Comment: The BQ CLI also has support for formatting results similarly.